# AI tools/LLM models to analyze excel data

Tags: python, nlp, data-analysis, excel, llm

I have a bunch of excel files containing information of employee attendance. I want to use NLP-based search to ask questions like: Which employee has taken most leaves?; What dates witness a high number of leave requests?; Which gender accounts for most leaves?, etc.

Are there any AI tools or LLM models that I can use to get answers to such queries by studying excel data?

NOTE: The tool should provide python APIs such that I can integrate it with my application.

Comment: There's julius.ai: https://julius.ai/ which is also available as a chatGPT plugin. It's cool that it shows the code it generates so you can copy/paste/correct as needed.

Comment: I'm actually looking for options that can provide python APIs. I updated my question. Please suggest tools with python Apis if you know any.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`pandas-llm` package](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-llm/)?